# how to show image from api in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

i have api and in that api **Author**, **discription** and **Image(url)** are present... now i  want to know how can i fetch that Image and show in html page

example api - https://randomuser.me/api/

Comment: Could you please add some code that you have tried ?

Comment: We don't know the API you're referring to.  You are encouraged to contact the owner/maintainer of the API for documentation on how to use it.  If you have an example of something you've tried that isn't working as expected, please demonstrate that example and explain the problem.

Comment: post updated^....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `XMLHttpRequest` and use `JSON.parse` to convert string to object.

To get image, use `data.results[0].picture.large`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>The XMLHttpRequest Object</p>

<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Request data</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
<img id="myimage" />

<script>
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      document.getElementById("myimage").src = data.results[0].picture.large
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "https://randomuser.me/api", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

---

Answer (score 2):

You could get the API result and set the `Image(url)` as the source of an `img` tag in HTML.

It might look like this in HTML:

```
<img id="myImg">
```

And then in JS:

```
var myApi = {"Author": "..", "Description": "..", "Image": "data://...."};
document.getElementById("myImg").src = myApi["Image"];
```